# How to swap mouse buttons AND touchpad taps INDEPENDENTLY?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, konsole

I alternate between left-handed and right-handed mouse on even/odd days for reasons not relevant here. I use for such thing a widget in Kubuntu 12.04

When it is left-handed day, my mouse understand wells that the primary button should be secondary and vice versa. The problem is that on those days the touchpad thinks "Hey, today one tap means secondary button" and it becomes nearly useless.

This happens because in the touchpad configuration settings of Kubuntu 12.04 you can assign **left** vs **right** mouse button to the action "Tapping with one finger", and not the **primary** vs **secundary** button. Therefore, on left-handed days one tap on the touchpad means "secondary".

Sure you linux experts can tell me a way to swap both mouse buttons and the meaning of touchpad taps INDEPENDENTLY and by konsole, so that I can run a script on even/odd days and forget about this nasty thing.

Comment: Did you ever figure out anything on this. Very cusious. Thanks

Comment: @pal4life No. Sorry. I am still with the same problem on Kubuntu 14.04. If I find a way, I will post it here.

Comment: @pal4life I found the trick for the left-handed mouse. See answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

First:

```
xinput -list
```

And write down the name of your mouse as it appears among other devices. Mine is "Logitech USB Optical Mouse". Then:

Right-handed:

```
xinput set-button-map "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" 1 2 3 &
```

Left-handed:

```
xinput set-button-map "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" 3 2 1 &
```

The touchpad is not affected.

For an explanation on how this works:

```
man xinput
```

Comment: Alternatively, use the `synclient` tool, as explained http://askubuntu.com/a/673084/28943