# Touchpad not working on alternate boots. Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: boot, drivers, touchpad, laptop, 20.10

When I boot into ubuntu, the touchpad works. After a reboot it doesn't. After another reboot it does work. But anyways mouse works all the time. Gets pretty inconvenient sometimes. Why is this happening? Well I don't know. But in case my touchpad stops working when I boot, I need to reboot ubuntu and it starts working again. Tried reinstalling os, tried live usbs too. The same alternating trend is observed each time with the touchpad. Please help.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/971519/905106 you might want follow this answer. Everything is explained there.