# Move windows with double tap instead of click for gnome shell

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell

I switched from the default GNOME setup that comes with Ubuntu to vanilla gnome 3.36.8 (AFAIK, I changed it from a settings icon at the bottom right of the login screen out of curiosity from what it was)

It looks really nice and I want to switch to it, but an unusually annoying inconvenience is that I could normally move/resize windows with a soft double tap (no push-down click), but now I have to push down a single time on the title bar to start resizing windows.

Now, how could I revert to the default behavior when I installed Ubuntu, where you could resize windows with a double tap?

EDIT: I couldn't right click either, which I discovered when trying to right-click on a youtube video. I rebooted the computer, changed the DE to Ubuntu, and when I did the exact same thing it worked...

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can turn a double tap into a click thanks to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/971519/1195829

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true`

Changing right click/double click to what I used on the default Ubuntu installation can be changed in GNOME tweaks > Keyboard & mouse > Mouse click emulation, and changing the selected option to  "Area"

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a feature of the updated shell; it didn't use to be a part of the interface. I think changing the old GUI to have the new feature might be a matter of tweaking the shell rather than just selecting an option. I hope you get a more hopeful answer than this, as I can't help with the coding and shell design stuff.

The lack of a context menu upon right clicking is more concerning. That should work. Does the context menu come up when you right click on things outside of the browser?

Comment: Well, after a bit of experimenting I found out that I had to double click in the middle of the touchpad, when I was used to double clicking at the bottom .

I can change it to right click in GNOME Tweaks "mouse click emulation" and then double click with how I do it works. 

Unfortunately I can't mark this as an accepted answer since it does not solve anything.

Comment: that's some good news, mate. cool. :)